# Where does רבי שמעון בר נחמי learn that different places have different designated times to read the Megilah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah

On מגילה: דף ב:א there's a מחלוקת between רבי שמעון בר נחמי & רב שמן בר אבא about where in the תורה is it hinted that we read the מגילה on י"א י"ב & י"ג. I have thought of a question on רבי שמעון בר נחמי who holds we learn it out from "כימים":

The גמרא:

> הֵיכָא רְמִיזָא? אָמַר רַב שֶׁמֶן בַּר אַבָּא אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן,
> אָמַר קְרָא: ״לְקַיֵּים אֵת יְמֵי הַפּוּרִים הָאֵלֶּה בִּזְמַנֵּיהֶם״,
> זְמַנִּים הַרְבֵּה תִּקְּנוּ לָהֶם. הַאי מִיבַּעְיָא לֵיהּ לְגוּפֵיהּ!
> אִם כֵּן לֵימָא קְרָא ״זְמַן״, מַאי ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ — זְמַנִּים טוּבָא.
> וְאַכַּתִּי מִיבְּעֵי לֵיהּ: ***זְמַנּוֹ שֶׁל זֶה לֹא כִּזְמַנּוֹ שֶׁל
> זֶה!*** אִם כֵּן, לֵימָא קְרָא ״זְמַנָּם״, מַאי ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ —
> שָׁמְעַתְּ מִינַּהּ כּוּלְּהוּ. אֵימָא זְמַנִּים טוּבָא! ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״
> דּוּמְיָא דִּ״זְמַנָּם״: מָה ״זְמַנָּם״ תְּרֵי — אַף ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״
> תְּרֵי. וְאֵימָא תְּרֵיסַר וּתְלֵיסַר? כִּדְאָמַר רַב שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר
> יִצְחָק: שְׁלֹשָׁה עָשָׂר זְמַן קְהִילָּה לַכֹּל הִיא, וְלָא צְרִיךְ
> לְרַבּוֹיֵי, הָכָא נָמֵי: שְׁלֹשָׁה עָשָׂר זְמַן קְהִילָּה לַכֹּל
> הִיא, וְלָא צְרִיךְ לְרַבּוֹיֵי. וְאֵימָא שִׁיתְּסַר וְשִׁיבְסַר!
> ״וְלֹא יַעֲבוֹר״ כְּתִיב. וְרַבִּי שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָנִי אָמַר,
> אָמַר קְרָא: ״כַּיָּמִים אֲשֶׁר נָחוּ בָהֶם הַיְּהוּדִים״. ״יָמִים״,
> ״כַּיָּמִים״ — לְרַבּוֹת אַחַד עָשָׂר וּשְׁנֵים עָשָׂר. וְאֵימָא
> תְּרֵיסַר וּתְלֵיסַר! אָמַר רַב שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר יִצְחָק: שְׁלֹשָׁה
> עָשָׂר זְמַן קְהִילָּה לַכֹּל הִיא, וְלָא צְרִיךְ לְרַבּוֹיֵי.
> וְאֵימָא שִׁיתְּסַר וְשִׁיבְסַר! ״וְלֹא יַעֲבוֹר״ כְּתִיב. רַבִּי
> שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָנִי מַאי טַעְמָא לָא אָמַר מִ״בִּזְמַנֵּיהֶם״?
> ״זְמַן״ ״זְמַנָּם״ ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ לָא מַשְׁמַע לֵיהּ. וְרַב שֶׁמֶן בַּר
> אַבָּא מַאי טַעְמָא לָא אָמַר מִ״כַּיָּמִים״? אָמַר לָךְ: הָהוּא
> לְדוֹרוֹת הוּא דִּכְתִיב.

רבי שמעון בר נחמי learns out from the word "כימים", that we read the מגילה on י"א & י"ב, unlike רב שמן בר אבא, who learns it out from the word "בזמניהם".
רב שמן בר אבא learns that different places have different designated times from the word "בזמניהם".
But according to רבי שמעון בר נחמי, how does he know that different places have different designated times?

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered this question in [your first post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134396/why-doesn-t-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99-accept-%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%90-explanation-about-%D7%91%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9D), but I realize that was closed and others may want to discuss.

The gemara asks on 2b how do we know walled and unwalled cities read on separate days. The stam answers that it's from the phrase zmaneihem, which teaches there are multiple times. So presumably Rav Shimon bar Nachmani would agree with that.
The way I understand the "zman - zmanam - zmaneihem" drash is as follows: if there was just one day, the pasuk would just say zmano. Everyone agrees that the plural language means there are at least two different days. But Rav Shemen bar Ada makes an additional drash that there are two more days because he thinks there is a "double plural," whereas Rav Shimon bar Nachmani thinks zmaneihem is a regular, grammatically correct plural (or doesn't care about that fine distinction).